# Turn dataframe to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with three columns: pid, idx and value, like this...
[image]

I need to convert it to a dictionary where the key is pid and the value is array of tuples(idx, value)

It should look something like this

```
1 2:0.5 3:0.12 10:0.9 2000:0.3
0 4:1.0 78:0.6 1009:0.2
1 33:0.1 34:0.98 1000:0.8 3300:0.2
1 34:0.1 389:0.32
```

I'm really stuck on this. Please help

Comment: Where is an array of Tuples in your expected results?

Comment: Hi. Can you please include the dataset in your question in a form that we can copy-paste it? Rather than as image. Only 4 or 5 rows of the dataset suffice, not the whole thing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples for ideas of how to write the dataset in python

Comment: Never mind, I was impatient and made my own.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code) or [table formatting](/editing-help#tables).

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'pid': [78, 78, 190,190,190], 
                   'idx': [20, 164, 1446,1447,1545],
                   'value':[0.01245,0.54154,0.24,0.98,09.654]})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate on the rows, adding new entry `row['pid']` to the dictionary at each iteration.

You can use `d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)` to avoid a tedious `if k in d: d[k].append(v) else: d[k] = [v]`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'pid': [78,78,78,99971,99971,99971], 'idx': [20,164,175,1451,1452,1453], 'value': [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.090909,0.090909,0.090909]})

d = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    d.setdefault(row['pid'], []).append((row['idx'], row['value']))

print(d)
# {78.0: [(20.0, 0.0), (164.0, 0.0), (175.0, 0.0)], 99971.0: [(1451.0, 0.090909), (1452.0, 0.090909), (1453.0, 0.090909)]}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the function below for this. How can I do it?

Comment: `def bag_to_svmlight(input):
    return ' '.join(( "%d:%f" % (fid, float(fvalue)) for fid, fvalue in input))`

Comment: @Kin_99 If `d` is the dictionary built in my answer, then you can do `new_d = {k: ' '.join(f'{i}:{v}' for i,v in l) for k,l in d.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

You can group by 'pid' then aggregate with `zip`:

```
result = (
    df.groupby('pid')
      .apply(lambda f: list(zip(f['idx'].tolist(), f['value'].tolist())))
      .to_dict()
)
```

Comment: hmm, this doesn't seem to work